# SQL: Assigning sequence numbers

Tags: sql, sqlite

I would like to assign a sequence number as I add a group of rows to a table. How do I do this? I thought about using COUNT() or ROWID but I cannot figure out how.

Let's say I have a table with three columns: PlayListID, TuneID and SequenceNum

I want to create a new tune playlist, so I'm going to add a bunch of TuneID values for a PlayListID of 2 for example. The TuneIDs are ordered by artist, album and track number. Here's what I have at present:

```
SELECT TuneID From Tunes
WHERE ArtistID=2
ORDER BY AlbumID, TrackNum
```

I guess what I am trying to do is preserve the ordering information - ensure that when all tunes  for `PlayListID=2` are retrieved, they have a column that indicates their order. `TrackNum` cannot be used as their may be a number of albums and I may write another query to retrieve them in some other order as well.

So, how would I modify the below command to add an ascending column (sequence) value for each row inserted?

```
INSERT INTO Playlist (Name,Seq)
SELECT Name, ??? As Seq FROM Tunes
WHERE ArtistID=2
ORDER BY AlbumID, TrackNum
```

I'm using SQLite. I don't want to use autoincrement because I'd like the Seq number to be 1 for each PlaylistID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SQL genius at work solved my problem. Here's the solution - creating a temporary table which has an auto incrementing column..

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE New_Playlist (Seq INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, TuneID INTEGER);

INSERT INTO New_Playlist (TuneID)
SELECT TuneID FROM Tunes
WHERE ArtistID=2
ORDER BY AlbumID, Track;

INSERT INTO Playlist (TuneID, Name, Seq)
SELECT t.TuneID, t.Name, np.Seq
FROM New_Playlist np JOIN Tunes t ON t.TuneID = np.TuneID;

DROP TABLE New_Playlist;
```

Answer (score -1):

try thiz :
INSERT INTO Playlist (Name,Seq)
SELECT Name,rownum FROM Tunes
WHERE ArtistID=2
ORDER BY AlbumID, TrackNum;

Comment: and what is `rownum`?

Comment: In SQLite, there's no function named `rownum`.

Comment: k send the table structure for tunes table

Comment: But the used asked to solve the problem using SQLite. Refine your answer.

Comment: @Hrithu: Tunes only contains Name varchar, artistid, albumid and tracknum which are all integer types.

Comment: Is there any column having auto increment with primary key in table (unique integer field)

Comment: @Hrithu: No but the Seq column cannot have unique values either. Each playlistid should start from 1.